# need assistance with basic objective-c build error

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have no experience at all at objective-c, only now started.
A developer I work with had to go abroad for a few days, and by mistake left an error in the code, and now I cannot compile an Iphone application to finish it...

I got some information from him by mail, and he told me that he left a library that is called dialog and that I need to remove it to make it work...

The thing is that I have no experience in objective-c and Xcode... i'm the web developer :)

i tried to run the project, and got this error:

> Build target mormar
>
> Ld
>   /Users/yanivshimony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mormar-cxfykryhzfovlbgtsjfowgleiyxu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mormar.app/mormar
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/yanivshimony/Desktop/mormar
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/yanivshimony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mormar-cxfykryhzfovlbgtsjfowgleiyxu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/yanivshimony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mormar-cxfykryhzfovlbgtsjfowgleiyxu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/yanivshimony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mormar-cxfykryhzfovlbgtsjfowgleiyxu/Build/Intermediates/mormar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mormar.build/Objects-normal/i386/mormar.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o
>   /Users/yanivshimony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mormar-cxfykryhzfovlbgtsjfowgleiyxu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mormar.app/mormar
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in LoadingView.o   "_kCATransitionFade", referenced from:
>         +[LoadingView loadingViewInView:] in LoadingView.o
>         -[LoadingView removeView] in LoadingView.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

after googling this for a while, I still have no idea how to solve this... 
I would greatly appreciate any help,
thanks!

Comment: Did you link your project with CoreAnimation framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link against QuartzCore.

Click on your project name in the Xcode sidebar. Then click on your target, and in the Summary tab find the list of linked frameworks and libraries. Click the plus button below this list, and add QuartzCore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It might sound silly, but the client is on a hurry and we didn't see this error coming and now he's happy :) thanks!

Comment: No worries. It's never silly to ask questions when you're learning :)

Answer (score 2):

You need QuartzCore framework. Add it to your project (through project setting's "Link binary" build phase). Add the `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to project's prefix header (usually `Prefix.pch` or `{ProjectName}-Prefix.pch`). This should solve the problem without removal of this library.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I chose the second answer simply because it was dummy proof :) But thanks so much...